# How can I check if user is already Logged in using aws cognito user pool anywhere in project?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I am doing SSO(Single Sign On) in my application. I am making use of AWS cognito for it and user pool and Identity pool for users.

I have setup user pool, identity pool and using hosted UI.

When I am using Custom UI for login and calling below cognito function:

```
        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
          onSuccess: function (result) {
            var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            AWS.config.region = config.region;
            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                IdentityPoolId : config.IdentityPoolId, // your identity pool id here
                Logins : {
                    'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<pool-id>': result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                }
            });

            //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
            AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
            console.log("in refresh");
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully logged!');
                }
            });
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            console.log("in failure");
            alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        },

        mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
            // MFA is required to complete user authentication.
            // Get the code from user and call
            console.log("in mfa required");
            cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, this)
        }
      });
```

This works fine but I am not able to redirect user to routes on successful and failure.

I want to use hosted UI.

Now I am able to successfully authenticate user from hosted UI and redirect to URL provided in app client settings callback URL. And getting id_token, access_token in url. I am able to decode it and get username from that.

But when I do:

```
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(config.poolData);
console.log("cog user: ", userPool.getCurrentUser());
```

I get null.

Is there any way to get current logged in user So that I can identify if user is logged in or not and do next operations accordingly.

Comment: Instead of `var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(config.poolData)` use global.userPool

Comment: @Jishnu I am getting error as global.userPool is not a function